# Firefox 60 CSD Window Buttons Left

Tags: firefox

I like the new CSD option (remove title bar) but when activated my window buttons move over to the right (normally on the left). Is there a way to have CSD enabled but with buttons on the left?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Create the file "userChrome.css" and its parent directory "chrome" if they don't already exist:

```
~/.mozilla/firefox/<YOUR_FIREFOX_PROFILE>/chrome/userChrome.css
```

Place the following code in userChrome.css
If the line that begins with @namespace is already in your userChrome.css, don't add it a second time.

```
#TabsToolbar {
  direction: rtl;
}

#tabbrowser-tabs {
  direction: ltr;
}

.titlebar-buttonbox {
  display: flex;
}

.titlebar-min {
  order: 2;
}

.titlebar-max {
  order: 1;
}

.titlebar-close {
  order: 3;
  margin-right: 6px !important;
}
```

Now restart Firefox and the buttons will be on the left.

Your Firefox profile will look something like this: hej3q2i1.default
If you aren't sure which profile is yours, you can find out by following these steps:

1. Open Firefox
2. Click the menu button
3. Click Help
4. Select Troubleshooting Information
5. Your Firefox profile will be the last directory listed in "Profile
   Directory"

CSS source: https://gist.github.com/oidualc/9f7c0a6591ada0d391ee6813a518dc3b[image]

Comment: Thanks for trying but this does not solve the problem, the buttons are still over on the right in CSR mode.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood. I assumed you meant CSD mode because I've never heard of CSR mode and CSD mode allows you to merge tabs with the titlebar. If you do mean CSD mode (Client Side Decorations), this does work. Double check your work and restart Firefox after making the changes. I have added a screenshot to my answer showing the results.

Comment: I tried it on a different computer and it does indeed work, not sure what I was doing wrong before. Yes I did mean CSD, I think I must have been half asleep the other day. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. If you get a moment, please edit your title and question to say CSD instead of CSR so it's easier for others to find.

Comment: This makes the window buttons to placed on the left but they are not placed properly. The space between minimize and close buttons is too small compared to the space between maximize and minimize button.

Comment: Like [this](https://imgur.com/a/b1r5PmK).

Comment: since 5/24/2019 custom CSS is no longer loaded on startup by default. You have to enable `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` in your `about:config`

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [@denshigomi's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1035448/857816), I added a poperty for the misalignment. This fixes the [Apoorv Potnis's issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035428/firefox-60-csd-window-buttons-left/1035448#comment1722728_1035448). You can add this property to userChrome.css file:

```
#titlebar-close {
  margin-right: 6px !important;
}
```

Also the gist can be found in [here](https://gist.github.com/isacikgoz/512c8e33fe2c91906384ad8ef644787b).

Answer (score 2):

Original author of the [gist](https://gist.github.com/oidualc/9f7c0a6591ada0d391ee6813a518dc3b) here.
The script has been updated because in the latest versions of Firefox Nightly the buttons order has been inverted.

- Type about:support on the URL bar
- Open the "Profile Directory" ( /home/.../.mozilla/firefox/... )
- Create if it doesn't exist already a directory named "chrome"
- Create a file inside (if it doesn't exist already) named userChrome.css
- Append the following code

userChrome.css:

```
#TabsToolbar {
    direction: rtl;
}

#tabbrowser-tabs {
    direction: ltr;
}

.titlebar-buttonbox {
    display: flex;
}

.titlebar-min {
    order: 2;
}

.titlebar-max {
    order: 1;
}

.titlebar-close {
    order: 3;
    margin-right: 6px !important;
}
```

Further information can be found here: https://www.userchrome.org/

Answer (score 1):

This works for me after the Firefox 65 update:

(userChrome.css)

```
#menubar-items {
  -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.titlebar-buttonbox-container {
  -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1!important;
}

.titlebar-button.titlebar-close {
  -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
}

.titlebar-button.titlebar-min {
  -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
}

.titlebar-button.titlebar-max {
  -moz-box-ordinal-group: 3;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help!

I had to change it a bit, but it's perfect now!

This is my 'userChrome.css' file, now:

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");

#titlebar-max {
  -moz-box-ordinal-group: 0;
}

#titlebar-content {
  direction: rtl;
}

#TabsToolbar {
  direction: rtl;
}

#tabbrowser-tabs {
  direction: ltr;
}

.tabbrowser-tab:not([pinned="true"]):hover .tab-close-button:not([selected="true"]) {
  display: -moz-box !important;
}

#menubar-items {
  -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.titlebar-buttonbox-container {
  -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1!important;
}

.titlebar-button.titlebar-close {
  -moz-box-ordinal-group: 3;
  margin-left: 5px !important;
  margin-right: 6px !important;
}

.titlebar-button.titlebar-min {
  -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
}

.titlebar-button.titlebar-max {
  -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Gnome for Firefox 65 this userChrome works best for me.

[image: sample with user chrome]

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");


#TabsToolbar .toolbar-items {
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
}

#TabsToolbar-customization-target .titlebar-spacer[type="pre-tabs"] {
    display: none;
}

#TabsToolbar-customization-target .titlebar-spacer[type="post-tabs"] {
    width: 4px !important;
}

.titlebar-buttonbox-container {
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1 !important;
}

.titlebar-buttonbox-container toolbarbutton.titlebar-button.titlebar-close {
    margin-left: 4px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the buttons in the ubuntu style order

Close - Min - Max

then you have to add one property to @PauloHortas solution from above to the css

```
.titlebar-buttonbox {
   direction: ltr;
}
```

but then it works perfectly nice with firefox 73 and Ubuntu 19.10